# SwiftUI: Button without Label/String in the initializer but with ButtonStyle

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

SwiftUI has a few `Button` initializers, but all of them require either a `String` or `some View` as the parameter alongside with the `action`.

However, the button's appearance can also be customized with the help of `ButtonStyle`s which can add custom views to it.

Let's consider a Copy button with the following icon:

[image: SF Symbols Copy]

The style I've made for the button looks as follows:

```
struct CopyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    init() {}

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        let copyIconSize: CGFloat = 24
        return Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: copyIconSize, height: copyIconSize)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("copy_button")
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, however, I have to initialize the `Button` with an empty string at call site:

```
Button("") {
    print("copy")
}
.buttonStyle(CopyButtonStyle())
```

So, the question is how can I get rid of the empty string in the button's initialization parameter?

**Potential Solution**

I was able to create a simple extension that accomplishes the job I need:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Button where Label == Text {
    init(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.init("", action: action)
    }
}
```

Call site:

```
Button() { // Note: no initializer parameter
    print("copy")
}
.buttonStyle(CopyButtonStyle())
```

But curious, whether I'm using the `Button` struct incorrectly and there is already a use-case for that, so that I can get rid of this extension.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way than making a `ButtonStyle` configuration is to pass in the label directly:

```
Button {
    print("copy")
} label: {
    Label("Copy", systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
}
```

This also comes with some benefits:

1. By default, the button is blue to indicate it can be tapped
2. No weird stretching of the image that you currently have
3. No need to implement how the opacity changes when pressed

---

You could also refactor this into its own view:

```
struct CopyButton: View {
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Label("Copy", systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        }
    }
}
```

Called like so:

```
CopyButton {
    print("copy")
}
```

Which looks much cleaner overall.

Comment: I have a palette of other `ButtonStyle`s which might not use SF Symbols or which use text, so this would be of too custom of a solution. Note, I'd like to get rid of the initializer param, not of the style support or create a completely custom type. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a right way for what you are trying to do, you do not need make a new ButtonStyle for each kind of Button, you can create just one and reuse it for any other Buttons you want. Also I solved your Image stretching issue with `.scaledToFit()`.

```
struct CustomButtonView: View {
    
    let imageString: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let identifier: String
    let action: (() -> Void)?
    
    init(imageString: String, size: CGFloat = 24.0, identifier: String = String(), action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.imageString = imageString
        self.size = size
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        return Button(action: { action?() } , label: {
            
            Image(systemName: imageString)
               .renderingMode(.template)
               .resizable()
               .scaledToFit()
               .frame(width: size, height: size)
               .accessibilityIdentifier(identifier)
            
        })
        .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())

    }
    
}

struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        return configuration.label
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

---

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomButtonView(imageString: "doc.on.doc", identifier: "copy_button", action: { print("copy") })

    }
}
```

Comment: "Also I solved your Image stretching issue" -> no need to, the icon I use is a custom one, there is no stretching issue with that one. The icon presented here is just for reference, the question only about the API (programming)

Comment: I can just see the code in question, in the question there is stretching issue! Ps: it is my style of answering that I am trying solve or refactoring any issue in question. You can do you.

Comment: No problem and thanks for solving it and proposing your version. For this question I've just replaced my custom icon (which fits perfectly) with the default one, so that it's still clear what the question is all about.

Comment: I already answered you in my last comment about my style of answering! So it make no seance that you are bolding about what the question is all about! And also I mentioned: You do you! It means do your style! I do my style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EmptyView` for label, like

```
    Button(action: { // Note: no initializer parameter
         print("copy")
    }, label: { EmptyView() })
    .buttonStyle(CopyButtonStyle())
```

but wrapping it in custom button type (like shown in other answer) is more preferable from re-use and code readability point of view.

Comment: Still, need to add an `EmptyView` at call site. I'd simply prefer to get rid of it.
Looks like the extension and an init method are the simplest solutions here.